# Возможно ли работать одновременно с DATAJPA и JDBC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

Для работы с БД я использую в приложении `Spring DATAJPA`. Сейчас я хочу реализовать часть операций на чистом `JDBC` *(в этих операциях не требуется работать напрямую с сущностями)*, но возникла проблема.

`DATAJPA` использует один transactionManager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
              p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

А `JDBC` другой:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Насколько я понимаю, я не могу просто так взять и подключить оба менеджера транзакций одновременно, потому что Spring не сможет понять что к чему. Как мне тогда работать одновременно и с `JDBC` и с `DATAJPA`? Возможно ли это вообще?